# How to play a video on full screen and able to turn volume down/up in cypress?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I am trying to figure out how to play video on full screen but my code is not working:

```
cy.get('[class="shaka-fullscreen-button material-icons-round shaka-tooltip"]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('contain', 'fullscreen').click()
```

I am able to play the video on mute but I want to test the volume can be reduced but cant get this working.

Code for starting video on default screen on mute:

```
cy.get('#video')
.then((video) => {
  const element = video.get(0);
  element.muted = true;
  element.play();
  return video;
})
```

div (Element code):

```
<button class="shaka-mute-button material-icons-round shaka-tooltip" aria-label="Mute">volume_up</button>
<div class="shaka-range-container shaka-volume-bar-container" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 255, 255) 76.8111%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54) 76.8111%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54) 100%);">
    <input class="shaka-range-element shaka-volume-bar" type="range" step="any" min="0" max="1" aria-label="volume">
</div>
<button class="shaka-fullscreen-button material-icons-round shaka-tooltip" aria-label="Full screen">fullscreen</button>
```

Comment: I believe there is a fullscreen toggle and volume control attributes for a video. Have you given those a try?

Comment: @jjhelguero thanks for your comment. I have not seen any fullscreen toggle and volume control attributes for a video. Where can I find more info on this please?